# Check if user set a custom color in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, colors, accessibility

Is it possible to check if the user set custom fore- and background colors for e.g. accessibility purposes with JS (jQuery)?

The only way I know is to check both background and foreground color of an element if the default color is known. If those vary, the colors could have be set in the browser settings.

Comment: I don't think so, but see [W3C's CSS UI Doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#system-colors), and see if that helps

Comment: What would you do with such an information?

Comment: @FelipeAls: You mean the information about the fore- and background colors? There's element on my site which got visualized wrong if the user uses custom colors. If I'm able to check if those colors got customized I can also customize that element. ;)

Comment: All elements can be visualized wrong with custom colors. Where would it end? That's not your responsibility to correct the choice made by some of your users. Do respect their choice (or inform them, maybe); too bad for them if they decide to change colors and they do it poorly. Or maybe they still have good reasons to choose these colors, reasons that we ignore completely.

Answer (score 0):

I indeed check if after page load the background-color and color have changed. If so, I make some modifications via JS. That's my solution for now. :)

Best Regards

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't possible. If a user is using a custom stylesheet, or forcing the broswer to do  stuff, there's no way to sniff that to my knowledge. There used to be a way to overrule them but that died out back in IE 6 or 7... you probably still can with some sketcky JS